# Spreadsheet add-on manifest Timezone

Tags: google-apps-script, timezone, manifest.json

So I want my addon to use users timezone in its functions, how do I set it in manifest?

```
{
  "oauthScopes": [
    "https://www.googleapis.com/auth/gmail.readonly",
    "https://www.googleapis.com/auth/gmail.send",
    "https://www.googleapis.com/auth/spreadsheets",
    "https://www.googleapis.com/auth/script.container.ui",
    "https://www.googleapis.com/auth/script.scriptapp",
    "https://www.googleapis.com/auth/userinfo.email",
    "https://www.googleapis.com/auth/script.storage"
  ],
  "dependencies": {
  },
  "exceptionLogging": "STACKDRIVER",
  "timeZone": "GMT"
}
```

I mean addon might be used by users from US or India and they should run addon with their timezone.

Comment: If you want to modify Manifests file (``appsscript.json``) using Google Apps Script, how about using this library? https://github.com/tanaikech/ManifestsApp If this was not what you want, I'm sorry.

Answer (score 0):

You only need the following scope in the manifest file for retrieving the user's timezone.

```
https://www.googleapis.com/auth/spreadsheets
```

Then use the SpreadsheetApp service to get the default timezone of the current spreadsheet which is likely the timezone of the user as well.

```
var ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();
Logger.log(ss. getSpreadsheetTimeZone());
```

Comment: Amit, thanks for the reply, I understood how to get the timezone from your comment, but how do you set it and override Manifest timezone? That's what I asked for.